# Combining multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this thing I don't know how to solve.

TABLE 1: ITEMS

```
ID | NO_ 
1 | SX1234
2 | SXABCD
```

TABLE 2: Text

```
Reffilename | RefKey | LanguageCode | ID | LineNumber | Txt1
Product | SX1234 | ENU | 2 | 0 | This is
Product | SX1234 | ENU | 2 | 1 | my text
Product | SX1234 | ENU | 2 | 2 | I want to come 
Product | SX1234 | ENU | 2 | 3 | out in one field
....
```

I can do this

```
SELECT i.[No]_, t.[Txt1] 
FROM ITEMS AS i
INNER JOIN 
TEXT AS t ON i.[no_] = t.RefKey
WHERE t.Reffilename = 'Prouduct' AND t.LanguageCode = 'ENU' AND t.ID = 2 AND i.[No_] = 'SX1234'
```

Thats give me this result.

```
SXI1234 | This is
SXI1234 | my text
SXI1234 | I want to come
SXI1234 | out in one field
```

But I want to merge the text, so my output will come:

```
SXI1234 | This is my text I Want to come out in one field
```

How do i solve this?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I use MS SQL server

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-microsoft-sql-server-2005

Comment: Try using STUFF() u can easily achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.RefKey,Stuff((SELECT ''+ Txt1  FROM Text
where a.Id=b.Id
 FOR
 XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'),1,2,N''
) As Text 
from ITEMS a
group by a.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `STUFF()` function

```
SELECT i.[No]_, text= STUFF((
    SELECT ', ' + t.[Txt1] 
    FROM ITEMS AS a
    INNER JOIN 
    TEXT AS t ON i.[no_] = t.RefKey
    WHERE a.[No]_= i.[No]_
    FOR XML PATH, TYPE).value(N'.[1]', N'varchar(max)'), 1, 2, '')
FROM ITEMS AS i
GROUP BY i.[No]_
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @t1 TABLE (Id INT, Num CHAR (7))
INSERT INTO @t1
    VALUES (1, 'SX1234'), (2, 'SXABCD')
DECLARE @t2 TABLE (Reffilename Char(8), RefKey CHAR (7), LanguageCode  CHAR(4), ID INT, LineNumber INT, Txt1 VARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO @t2
    VALUES ('Product', 'SX1234', 'ENU', 2, 0, 'This isa,
    ('Product', 'SX1234', 'ENU', 2, 1, 'my text'),
    ('Product', 'SX1234', 'ENU', 2, 2, 'I want to come'),
    ('Product', 'SX1234', 'ENU', 2, 3, 'out in one field')

SELECT DISTINCT RefKey, Result = STUFF((SELECT ' ' + t2.Txt1
                                FROM @t1 t1
                                JOIN @t2 t2 ON t1.Num = t2.RefKey 
                                FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '' ) 
FROM @t2
```

Comment: It would be beneficial if you explain your solution with more than just code. As the idea of SO is not to just copy some code that does 'the job' but also to learn :)

Comment: At first, declare all tables and variables (it’s clear). Then use function stuff(). First argument – query (add free space before each word, select query like XML), second – start from first symbol, third –  character length to remove, last - replaces the character length of the expression
I hope that I translated my thoughts correctly)